# How to compare items in a multi level object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object that is auto-generated that I need to obtain the data from, but first I need to clean it up so that there are no more duplicates and any additions are concatenated.

I currently have something like this example which is made up for illustrative purposes

```
const categories = [{
  category: "mammal",
  options: ["horse", "cow"],
}, {
  category: "mammal",
  options: ["pig", "cow"],
}, {
  category: "gender",
  options: ["male"],
}, {
  category: "mammal",
  options: ["cow"],
}, {
  category: "mammal",
  options: ["pig"],
}, {
  category: "gender",
  options: ["female"],
}];
```

What I am aiming for is to convert it into something like this:

```
mammal>horse;cow;pig/gender>male;female/
```

I have been successful by looping through the current array and comparing the properties of the objects, but I have failed to get any traction on looping through the options and appending them if they are not duplicates.

```
const newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    categoryIsInArray = newCat.indexOf(categories[i].category) !== -1;
    if (categoryIsInArray === true) {
         // do something with the options
    }
    else {
        newArr.push(categories[i].category)
    }
}
```

This results in a rather cut-down array:

```
["mammal","gender"]
```

I assume that I should be able to loop through the options and append them to their appropriate category if they don't already exist in that category. So I attempted a similar approach.

```
const newArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    categoryIsInArray = newCat.indexOf(categories[i].category) !== -1;
    if (categoryIsInArray === true) {
        for (let j = 0; j < categories[i].options.length; j++) {
            optionIsInArray = newCat.indexOf(categories[i].options[j]) !== -1;
            if(optionIsInArray === false) {
                newCat.push(categories[i].options)
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        newArr.push(categories[i].category)
    }
}
```

but that has just mashed up everything and is not what I want at all

```
 [
    'mammal',
    [
        'horse',
        'cow'
    ],
    [
        'horse',
        'cow'
    ],
    'gender',
    [
        'cow'
    ],
    [
        'horse'
    ],
    [
        'female'
    ]
]
```

How do I adjust this to get what I'm after ?

Comment: I don't get it do you always have just options or sometimes you `options` and sometimes `animal` instead?

Comment: @MoussaBistami There will always be options. The way the data is presented means that each category entry is accompanied by at least one option.

Comment: It seems that the original output I was aiming for has been edited from a string to a new object. Not sure why, maybe I didn't communicate it clearly

Comment: @UntitledGraphic ... it was indeed a miscommunication due to the provided attempt did never show any code that actually tried to produce a string based result. But anyhow, in order to achieve such an result one has to first normalize/unify the provided data-structure which was all your effort about.

Comment: @UntitledGraphic ... I'm going to restore the intended/expected final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by `category` and use a `Set` for unique options.

```js
const
    categories = [{ category: "mammal", options: ["chicken", "cow"] }, { category: "mammal", options: ["pig", "cow"] }, { category: "gender", options: ["male"] }, { category: "mammal", options: ["cow"] }, { category: "mammal", options: ["pig"] }, { category: "gender", options: ["female"] }],
    result = Object
        .entries(categories.reduce((r, { category, options }) => {
            options.forEach(Set.prototype.add, r[category] ??= new Set);
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(([key, values]) => `${key}>${[...values].join(';')}/`)
        .join('');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Before the edits, this was exactly what I was after. Unfortunately, my original question has been edited to alter the output string I wanted to achieve. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 1):

The next provided solution implements a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach as well. It differs in how the uniqueness of the final category arrays is achieved. One does always either initially create or reassign an instantly computed array of unique string values by [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)enating the currently processed `options` array to the initially empty, but later available, array which is/got grouped by a `category` specific key. The computation is done by creating a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#description) instance from the concatenated/merged array and immediately [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) it back into an array value.

```js
const optionsByCategoryLookup = categories
  .reduce((result, item) => {

    // - destructure the currently processed array item.
    const { category, options } = item;

    // - aggregate the final `result`, an object, used as lookup,
    //   which is going to feature key-value pairs (entries), where
    //   the key is the `category` value, and the value is ...
    result[category] = [
      // ... the ever newly calculated array 
      //     of unique `options` string-values.
      ...new Set(
        (result[category] ?? []).concat(options)
      )
    ];
    return result;  

  }, {});

console.log({ optionsByCategoryLookup });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const categories = [{
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["horse", "cow"],
  }, {
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["pig", "cow"],
  }, {
    category: "gender",
    options: ["male"],
  }, {
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["cow"],
  }, {
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["pig"],
  }, {
    category: "gender",
    options: ["female"],
  }];
</script>
```

And in case one want to re-use the reduce functionality, one does implement and provide it as e.g. function statement ...

```js
function aggregateCategoryBasedOptionsLookup(
  result, { category, options }
) {
  result[category] = [
    ...new Set(
      (result[category] ?? []).concat(options)
    )
  ];
  return result;  
}

const optionsByCategoryLookup = categories
  .reduce(aggregateCategoryBasedOptionsLookup, {});

console.log({ optionsByCategoryLookup });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const categories = [{
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["horse", "cow"],
  }, {
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["pig", "cow"],
  }, {
    category: "gender",
    options: ["male"],
  }, {
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["cow"],
  }, {
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["pig"],
  }, {
    category: "gender",
    options: ["female"],
  }];
</script>
```

**Edit**

And since the OP in the beginning was not really clear about the finally expected result one can built at the above approach.

One anyhow has to undergo the process of unifying/normalizing the provided data-structure. Thus the lookup object would serve as an intermediate result from which one does compute the final string based result (which once again does proof the advantage of small re-usable implemented functions) ...

```js
function aggregateCategoryBasedOptionsLookup(
  result, { category, options }
) {
  result[category] = [
    ...new Set(
      (result[category] ?? []).concat(options)
    )
  ];
  return result;  
}
function createStringBasedCategoryGraph(lookup) {
  // mammal>horse;cow;pig/gender>male;female/
  return Object
    .entries(lookup)
    .map(([key, value]) =>
      `${ key }>${ value.join(';') }/`
    )
    .join('');
}

const categoryGraph = createStringBasedCategoryGraph(
  categories
    .reduce(aggregateCategoryBasedOptionsLookup, {})
);
console.log({ categoryGraph });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const categories = [{
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["horse", "cow"],
  }, {
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["pig", "cow"],
  }, {
    category: "gender",
    options: ["male"],
  }, {
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["cow"],
  }, {
    category: "mammal",
    options: ["pig"],
  }, {
    category: "gender",
    options: ["female"],
  }];
</script>
```

Comment: I was writing ALMOST the exact same! +1 for beating me at it. The only difference being `(result, { category, options })`. Clean & readable is the best.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your array to grouped sets with unique category values, then reduce again to convert sets to arrays. The final result can be converted to any string you want:

```js
const grouped = categories.reduce((r, {category, options}) => (options.forEach(o => (r[category]??=new Set).add(o)), r), {});
const result = Object.keys(grouped).reduce((r, key) => (r[key] = [...grouped[key]], r), {});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script>
const categories = [
    {
        category: "mammal",
        options: ["horse", "cow"]
    },
    {
        category: "mammal",
        options: ["pig", "cow"]
    },
    {
        category: "gender",
        options: ["male"]
    },
    {
        category: "mammal",
        options: ["cow"]
    },
    {
        category: "mammal",
        options: ["pig"]
    },
    {
        category: "gender",
        options: ["female"]
    }
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const categories = [{
  category: "mammal",
  animal: ["horse", "cow"],
}, {
  category: "mammal",
  options: ["pig", "cow"],
}, {
  category: "gender",
  options: ["male"],
}, {
  category: "mammal",
  options: ["cow"],
}, {
  category: "mammal",
  options: ["pig"],
}, {
  category: "gender",
  options: ["female"],
}];

const result = {};

for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    const currentCategory = categories[i].category;
    const currentOptions = categories[i].options || categories[i].animal || [];

    if (!result[currentCategory]) {
        // If the category doesn't exist in the result object, create an array for it
        result[currentCategory] = [];
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < currentOptions.length; j++) {
        const currentOption = currentOptions[j];
        if (result[currentCategory].indexOf(currentOption) === -1) {
            // If the option doesn't exist in the category, add it
            result[currentCategory].push(currentOption);
        }
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

This code initializes an empty object (result) to store the cleaned-up data. It then iterates through the original array, checks whether the category already exists in the result object, and adds the options to the corresponding category while ensuring no duplicates are added.

The resulting result object will have categories as keys, each associated with an array of unique options.